# Creating a relationship between two custom types in WordPress

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

This is perhaps a very basic Wordpress development question. I am aware about creating custom types in Wordpress. So I created a Product type and a Version type and I would like to be able to keep a one-to-many relationship between the two i.e. for every Product, I would like to be able to associate one or more Version items from the admin editor. What is the way to do this? I am not in favor of using plugins, so I was thinking, I would use some kind of a custom field array of IDs, to connect the two. Am I on the right way? If I have to use a plugin, which one should it be?

Comment: taxonomies were created for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this would be to add a meta box on your product admin page. That way you can create a drop down list on your product page with your versions. You can get more on adding meta boxes using add_meta_box [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box).

You add all required functions to your themes' functions.php, but to summarise you will need the following wp functions amongst others.

```
add_action 
add_meta_box 
update_post_meta
```

Looking up these functions in the Wordpress Codex (using google) will get you on your way. If you get stuck, post some code of what you have tried and take it from there. There are a number of tutorials/examples around. If you can do enough to create custom types this should not take you long.